# Lighten HTML by 50% by using click event listeners ?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was just reading this article **[HERE](http://cubiq.org/you-shall-not-flicker)**, the author says the following:

> Also try to keep your HTML structure as simple as possible. Remember
>   that the following:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="somewhere">Some text</a></li>
</ul>
```

Can be always replaced by:

```
<ul>
   <li onclick="window.location.href='somewhere'">Some text</li>
</ul>
```

> We just lightened the HTML structure by 50%. If you have 100 rows,
>   you’d have 100 tags instead of 200. (And of course I’d use even
>   listeners instead on inline onclick.

How really did we lighten the HTML by 50% ?? i did't quite get it. can anybody explain ?

Thank You.

Comment: that's pretty stupid advice if js is turned off

Comment: This is very bad advice.

Comment: @Ramanlfc , i am not looking for advice on unobstructed javascript  :) but thanks for the heads up !

Comment: That's pretty stupid advise, period, as the amount of bytes just increased, and you added an outdated inline event handler.

Comment: Also you just added 25 bytes _per `li` element_. This is horrible advice. Search engines will also have a harder time figuring out what your site is trying to do.

Comment: Guys be objective , answer the danm question .. don't give me your opinion !!

Comment: It's not an opinion, it's a fact

Comment: not quite 50% ... even the sample code has gone from 4 to 3 tags ... if there were 100 list items, you'd go from 201 to 101 tags ... not quite 50% ... let alone the rest of the markup

Comment: `<a href="somewhere" class="li">Some text</a>`. According to the article, this would be lightening the HTML by 75% (as we're also losing the `ul` element). To micro optimize by saving an HTML element is just silly.

Comment: Number of elements doesn't really matter that much, amount of bytes read would increase dramatically.

Comment: Ok so i guess the author was saying remove all the `<li><a></a></li>` and replace them with a single  `<li><a onclick="window.location.href='somewhere'"></a></li>`

Comment: yes, it's clear the sample code, if there were 100 "links" would decrease the number of tags by 100, and increase the file size by 1900 bytes ... swings and roundabouts, which is worse,  larger file size or larger number of tags

Comment: You'll also need to add some CSS to style the list items with cursor:pointer so they look a bit like links when you hover over them at least ... which means you either add in-line style (multiply that by 100) or a class to the ul and some css to target li's within a ul of certain class ... who is going to "benchmark" the difference between that and simple a tags within li and see which is better? nobody, because it's a pointless excercise

Comment: Hey guys, personally I don't know the reason for this advice, but I think no matter how much silly it may seem, it can be respected and be thought of at least because of curiosity!

Comment: Also note that the article you're reading is almost five years old. Things change, and people change their opinion in five years, especially when it comes to programming.

Comment: @JaromandaX Wow did't realize the author was really talking about a optimization that micro .. i really taught this was some kind of a trick , does seem a bit stupid now , never mind , i had to ask the question and thanks for your valuable inputs

Comment: @adeneo i absolutely made note of that , it still seems to be quoted in the documentation of a very `<em>Modern<em>` plugin here http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/ and thats what led me to the article ! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the author wants to state that there will be only **one** html tag per list item in (only **li** tag):

```
  <li onclick="window.location.href='somewhere'">Some text</li>
```

but there are two tags in this ( **a** and **li** tags):

```
<li><a href="somewhere">Some text</a></li>
```

However I don't know if this makes a difference in performance! and of course it will be disappointing if java script disabled as @Ramanlfc said. But again Javascript is a part of modern programming. Many SPAs don't work if it's disabled!

Answer (score 2):

> If you have 100 rows, you’d have 100 tags instead of 200

As mentioned, it must be about the absence of the anchor tag. The problem is, you have other kind of (more serious) problems described on the comments and this is a bad advice.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my 2 cents.

If the objective is to lighten/minify the HTML without any gzipping and relying on JavaScript for navigation then I'd go crazy and do something like:

```
<ul>
   <li data-go="somewhere">Some text</li>
</ul>
```

And as the author mentioned:

> (And of course I’d use event listeners instead on inline onclick.)

Do something in JavaScript:

```
var lis = document.querySelectorAll('li');
for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
    lis[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
     window.location.href = this.getAttribute('data-go');
    });
};
```

But as you might have guessed, this would be the height of my desperation. As I am on a crazy-byte-saving streak, I'd go on and use `class` attribute to store go-to location instead of `data-` ones.